# Prevent a string comparison process to compare the same pair of strings more than once

Tags: vba, dictionary

I need help to prevent a string comparison process to compare the same pair of strings more than once.

I've built this Vba Function - [Compare_2_Strings(Str1,Str2)] - that returns a Final Score percentage value (0% - 100%), representing the similarity between both strings, based on the results of the analysis performed on Str1 and Str2, using the algorithms (*Levenstein*, *Similarity* and *compareNameByWordsLevenshtein*). This Function is being called inside a process that will perform comparisons over more than 500.000 strings. My goal, in order to make this process faster, is to avoid comparing the same pair of strings more than once, checking whether the Str1 - Str2 comparison has already been made or vice versa, since the result will be the same.

this verification, that a pair has already been compared, should be faster than repeating the same comparison again by calling Compare_2_Strings (Str1, Str2), which runs in average about 50 milliseconds.

I've thought perhaps using a Dictionary (with .EXISTS property) to store concatenated strings already compared, like this (pseudo code):

```
With Dictionary
Do
    Get Both Str1 and Str2

    'check both possibilities
    if not .EXISTS("Str1" & "Str2") Or not .EXISTS("Str2" & "Str1") then 
         
         'Process Comparison
         Result_Score = Compare_2_Strings(Str1,Str2)
         
         'Add Key of compared strings
         .Add key:="Str1" & "Str2", Item:=Result_Score

     Endif

Loop until (eof)
End With
```

I know that we can't have duplicates on ".Key". Can we have them on ".Item"?
There are limitations on using 'Dictionary' with that amount of records?

Is there another way better an Fastest to achieve this goal with Vba? I think an Array to be a much slower...

Comment: **(a)** Yes, sure you can have duplicate items in a dictionary. **(b)** you are talking about 500.000 strings - that would give 500.000 * 500.000 / 2 entries in your dictionary. Assuming 100bytes for every entry, you would need (if my calculation is correct), 12.5 TB of data, and I think that answers already your question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. in your opinion it is preferable to analyze a pair more than once, instead of using the method with Dictionary.
But can you suggest a better approach, please?

Comment: Do you really plan to compare all 500.000 strings against all 500.000 strings? If yes, you need to think about a method to speed things up in the first place. If your estimation of 50ms per comparison is correct, your program would run 200 years - without storing and things like that. How do you store the strings? How do you plan to store the results? Remember that you are dealing with 500.000 * 500.000 / 2 results, thats 125 billion results - you need a very powerfull database setup to deal with this.

Comment: It would help to explain a little more exactly what your source data looks like: do you have just a single list and you want to perform a pairwise within-list comparison?  Do you need to store the result of each comparison (and how will you do that?)   ie. *without this specific optimization you're asking about* what is your overall plan?

Comment: Yes Tim, the idea is  perform a pairwise within-list comparison All by All.
I've tested the function [Compare_2_Strings(Str1,Str2], with two dummy names, ina 500.000 interaction (For - Next), and took 15 minutes global time.

Comment: If you remove all duplicates first then a nested loop like (eg) `For i =1 to n: For j=i+1 to n: Compare(list(i), list(j): Next j: Next i` will not compare the same two items > once

Comment: Thank you all for your help..